# how to copy existing subcategory into another category programatically in magento1?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin

How can I copy existingg subcategory into another category.Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small script to be run from command line:

```
<?php

if((php_sapi_name() !== 'cli') && empty($argv))
    die('Access Disabled, possible notified the admin of your attempt.' );

$start_time = microtime(true);
$initial_memory = memory_get_usage();
$initial_real_memory = memory_get_usage(true);

// Make it compatible with CLI
if(isset($argv) && isset($argv[1]) && isset($argv[2]))
{
    $fromId = explode(',',$argv[1]);
    $toId = $argv[2];
} else {
    echo "Need to pass parameters: [FROM] [TO]  ... \n";
}

// make sure there was passed the parameters 
if(!isset($fromId) || !isset($toId)) {
    die('From ID and To ID required');
}

// some servers had problems with php-CLI not 
// been properly installed 
ini_set('memory_limit','1512M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 900);

require_once('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app();


// check for multiple categories 
if(!is_array($fromId)){
    $fromId = array($fromId);
}

// pass multiple cats at once separated by comma
foreach ($fromId as $cat) {
    echo "Copying from cat: $cat into cat id: $toId ... \n";

    copyMagentoCategory($cat, $toId, $toStoreId);

    echo "End the copy process for: {$cat}! \n";
}


function copyMagentoCategory($fromId, $toId, $toStoreId)
{
    // You have to fake the Magento store Id otherwise it won't save information
    Mage::app()->getStore()->setId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

    $parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($toId);

    $parentCategoryId = $parentCategory->getId();

    /* @var $oldCategory Mage_Catalog_Model_Category  */
    $oldCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($fromId); 

// The ID of the category you want to copy.
// The actual Magento code 
    $newCategory = clone $oldCategory;
    $newCategory->setId(null);
    $newCategory->setStoreId($toStoreId);
    $newCategory->setName($oldCategory->getName());
    $newCategory->setCustomDesign($oldCategory->getCustomDesign());
    $newCategory->setPageLayout($oldCategory->getPageLayout());
    $newCategory->setCustomLayoutUpdate($oldCategory->getCustomLayoutUpdate());
    $newCategory->save();

    $newCategory->move($parentCategoryId);



    // copy add to each product the new category
    $products = $oldCategory->getProductCollection();

    foreach ($products as $product)
    {
        $product->getId();
        $categories = $product->getCategoryIds();
        $categories[] = $newCategory->getId();
        $product->setCategoryIds($categories);
        $product->save();
    }



    // if subcategories, run on each of them
    $subcategories = $oldCategory->getChildrenCategories();

    foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) {
        echo 'Processing category: ' . $subcategory->getId() . "\n";
        copyMagentoCategory($subcategory->getId(), $newCategory->getId(), $toStoreId);
    }


}
```

Save the code in a php file in magento root, eg: copycat.php and execute it in the following way:

```
php copycat.php 192,182 201
```

the upper code will copy the categories 192 and 182 to the parent category 201. You can also pass only one argument.

```
php copycat.php 192 201
```

If you don't have access to command line then just remove the upper check:

```
if((php_sapi_name() !== 'cli') && empty($argv))
```

And replace the `$argv[1]` with `$_GET['']`
Something like:

```
// Make it compatible with Browser request
if(isset($_GET['from']) && isset($_GET['to']) )
{
    $fromId = explode(',',$_GET['from']);
    $toId = $_GET['to'];
}
```

And the browser url request  would be:

```
http://mydomain.dev/copycat.php?from=192,182&to=201
```

Comment: Hi obsergiu, Thanks its working but site url shows http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/catalog/category/view/s/bikes/id/39/ but this is not my requirement. my requirement site url shows http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/bikes  how to find these problem.can you please help me?

Comment: you need to go to ```Catalog > URL Rewrite Management``` and make sure your category  is there.

Comment: Btw, also make sure in [System > Configuration > Catalog] to have in the sectinon  "Search Engine Optimization"  the "Set Create Permanent Redirect for URLs" enabled.